# Divide chat data into sessions

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in the csv for chats with my customers for the past year. It is all in order of their timestamps. I want to divide into sessions per customer so that I can analyze separate chat sessions.

```
Timestamp            Customer        Message
2019-06-22 04:37:32     x        Hello, I price for 10 pens?
2019-06-22 04:38:11     y        whats the price of a new book?
2019-06-22 04:38:23     x        can you place an order for 9 only
2019-06-22 05:12:10     y        Ok I want to order 1
2019-06-22 05:17:45     z        Hello 
2019-06-22 06:31:12     x        Please cancel my order
2019-06-23 12:13:02     y        I want to place an order for 100 pencils
```

I would want to segment this data in a way where I can group them according to some timeframe and then by the customer. If there is any better way too, to divide this into chat sessions, I'd be more than happy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A starting point would be to group your dataset within a time period (say 60 minutes), `count` how many messages within the timeframe per customer, and also `list()` all the messages per customer:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Convert to timestamp if needed
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], errors='coerce')  

# Perform the operation
res = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Timestamp', freq='60min'),'Customer']).agg({'Message': lambda m: m.tolist(),'Customer':'count'})

# Rename the columns
res.rename(columns = {'Customer':'cust_msgs_per_hour'},inplace=True)
```

The above will give you:

```
res.sort_values('Customer')
Out[264]: 
                                                                        Message  cust_msgs_per_hour
Timestamp           Customer                                                                       
2019-06-22 04:00:00 x         [Hello, I price for 10 pens?, can you place an...                   2
2019-06-22 06:00:00 x                                  [Please cancel my order]                   1
2019-06-22 04:00:00 y                         [whats the price of a new book?]                   1
2019-06-22 05:00:00 y                                    [Ok I want to order 1]                   1
2019-06-23 12:00:00 y                [I want to place an order for 100 pencils]                   1
2019-06-22 05:00:00 z                                                   [Hello]                   1
```

Comment: Thank you so much @sophods this solves most of my problem with helping me to divide each customer's text into a list and probably test with different time frames. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yoy may use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`. In this way your dataset is grouped by your desired column(s). I.e:

`grouped_data = df.groupby(by='Customer')` and then apply some function on the grouped object.

Check the documentation for further resources:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Answer (score 0):

To view the entries for a specific time range and a specific customer, first define a *start_time* and *end_time* for your session. Also specify which customer you wish to view:

```
#Example
start_time = pd.to_datetime('2019-06-22 04:37:32')
end_time = pd.to_datetime('2019-06-23 12:13:02  ')
customer_to_view = 'x'
```

and then use the following line of code to view the messages from the specified customer during the specified session:

`df[(df['Timestamp'] > start_time) & (df['Timestamp'] < end_time) ][df['Customer'] == customer_to_view]`

Output for the above example would be:

```
          Timestamp     Customer             Message
2   2019-06-22 04:38:23    x          can you place an order for 9 only
5   2019-06-22 06:31:12    x          Please cancel my order
```

Note: Remember to convert your 'Timestamp' column to a datetime object for this to work: This can be done using the following line of code:
`df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])`